# Name error: 'self' not defined - when calling a function to create in-class variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, nameerror

I have the following class:

```
class Documents:
    def __init__(self, input_file):
        self.input_file_ = input_file #List in which each element is a list of tokens
        
        assert type(self.input_file_) is list, 'Input file is not a list'
        assert type(self.input_file_[0]) is list, 'Elements in input file are not lists' #Only checks first instance, not all. But should suffice
                
    def get_vocabulary(self):
        vocabulary = set([el for lis in self.input_file_ for el in lis])
        return vocabulary, len(vocabulary) 
    
    vocabulary, vocabulary_size = self.get_vocabulary()
```

But when I try to execute it, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-34-4268f473c299>", line 1, in <module>
    class Documents:

  File "<ipython-input-34-4268f473c299>", line 30, in Documents
    vocabulary, vocabulary_size = self.get_vocabulary()

NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

This is a common error on SO. However, I have not found an answer in which the code has a similar structure.

Can someone explain to me why I get this error and how I can change my code so that I don't get an error?

Comment: What did you intend the statement `vocabulary, vocabulary_size = self.get_vocabulary()` inside your class to do? If you're trying to initialise instance variables, put `self.` in front of the variable names, and put it inside `__init__`. That's what `__init__` is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have it, `vocabulary, vocabulary_size = self.get_vocabulary()` is being executed *when the class is being defined*, so there is no `self`. The latter is the name of the first argument passed to methods of a class and is the instance of the class (that was previously created) on which to operate.

The proper way to do this would be to call `get_vocabulary()` method from the `__init__()` method when an instance of the class exists and is being initialized.

Here's what I mean:

```
class Documents:
    def __init__(self, input_file):
        self.input_file_ = input_file # List in which each element is a list of tokens
        self.vocabulary, self.vocabulary_size = self.get_vocabulary()

        assert type(self.input_file_) is list, 'Input file is not a list'
        assert type(self.input_file_[0]) is list, 'Elements in input file are not lists' # Only checks first instance, not all. But should suffice

    def get_vocabulary(self):
        vocabulary = set([el for lis in self.input_file_ for el in lis])
        return vocabulary, len(vocabulary)
```

Comment (off-topic):

In languages that have classes and support object-orientated code like Python, it's usually best to avoid type-checking as much as possible because it doesn't support [subtyping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping) — but you can overcome that limitation when it is done by using the built-in [`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) built-in function.

This implies that it would probably be better to do the following in your `__init__()` method:

```
    assert isinstance(self.input_file, list), 'Input file is not a list'
    assert isinstance(self.input_file_[0], list), 'Elements in input file are not lists' # Only checks first instance, not all. But should suffice
```